# Scipy Optimize Minimize function always returns the initial values

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am having trouble getting my scipy optimization to work, and I think it is because of my constraint. The goal of my code is to find the best x and y coordinates to place a label for a scatterplot point, without this label being close to an old label. My optimization is the Euclidean distance between the scatterplot point and the label point (so that the label is as close as possible to the point). My constraint checks all the used x and y values, and makes sure that the new label x and y values (nx and ny), are not close to any of the old x and y values. If either the x or y is within 1, then the constraint returns 1 instead of 0. This should be the correct way I think because the constraint is an "eq".

However, I am guessing the problem is that the constraint is not a smooth equation, so the optimization has no idea how to handle it.

Is there any alternative way I can solve this problem?

```
#SECTION 1: Scatterplot: Labeling Points
#optimize (minimize) Euclidean Distance
usedx = []
usedy = []

#bounds
b = (0,10)
bnds = (b,b)

#objective
def objective(x, y):
    nx = x[0]
    ny = x[1]
    ox = y[0]
    oy = y[1]
    p1 = (ox,oy)
    p2 = (nx, ny)
    return distance.euclidean(p1, p2)

#constraint
def constraint(p, x, y):
    test = 0
    nx = p[0]
    ny = p[1]
    for i in x:
        if abs(i - nx) < 1:
            test = 1
    for i in y:
        if abs(i - ny) < 1:
            test = 1
    return test
const = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint, 'args': (usedx, usedy)}

for i, txt in enumerate(selectedFirmCurrent.sht_fund_name):
    originaly = selectedFirmCurrent.iloc[i]['category_score']
    originalx = selectedFirmCurrent.iloc[i]['fund_score']
    originalpoint = [originalx, originaly]
    #initial guess
    p0 = (originalx, originaly -.25)
    #optimization
    solution = minimize(objective, args = originalpoint, x0 = p0,bounds = bnds,constraints = const)
    #variable assign
    newx = solution.x[0]
    newy = solution.x[1]
    usedx.append(newx)
    usedy.append(newy)
    print(originalx, ": ", newx)
    print(originaly, ": ", newy+0.25)
    #implement
    ax.annotate(txt, (originalx,originaly), (newx,newy), arrowprops= dict(arrowstyle = '->'))
```

Comment: I think this is also nonconvex. If you use absolute values in the objective, I think this can be formulated as MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model. Also, I am not sure you should do this one label at the time. You may get better results by solving for all label locations simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, I will look into MIP. How would I get absolute values into the objective? Maybe I could switch around the problem so that the objective is to maximize the distance between labels (however this might make the labels far away from their respective points). Also, you are definitely right. I think since I am solving for one label at a time, the first labels get the best locations and the last labels get the worst.

Comment: Instead of a Euclidean distance use a Manhattan distance.

Comment: See e.g. STEVEN ZORASTER, Integer Programming Applied To The Map Label Placement Problem,  https://utpjournals.press/doi/10.3138/9258-63QL-3988-110H

Comment: Thanks again Erwin, I feel like I should use Euclidean because I care about how close the label is to the point, and Euclidean is the best measure of this. That article looks like the exact problem I am trying to solve... I am going to spend tomorrow working on it before I give in and spend the $20 for the article though haha.

Comment: Quadratic models are more difficult than linear ones and restrict the number of solvers you can use. Especially if the no-overlap constraints are modeled with binary variables.